# Retrieve locale based on the Accept-Language in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization

I have a Spring Boot (`2.1.3.RELEASE`) application that uses Jersey to define the (RESTful) endpoints. I'm trying to read and propagate some messages based on the locale being sent by the user-agents.

I've configured these beans:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
  final AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver resolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
  resolver.setSupportedLocales(Arrays.asList(Locale.GERMANY, Locale.US));
  resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
  return resolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() { // Not sure if this is needed
  final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
  messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
  messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages");
  messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
  messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
  return messageSource;
}
```

...and also the bundles (inside `../src/main/resources/`) like: `messages.properties` (fallback), `messages_en_US.properties`, `messages_de_DE.properties`, etc.

Now, the challenge is that I'm not sure how to "read" the locale sent by the user-agents in order to read the messages from the bundles appropriately. I'm injecting a `MessageSource ms`, and programmatically reading messages like:

```
final Locale locale = ???
ms.getMessage("message.duplicate-token", null, locale);
```

Any clues?

> I've tried `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` but it's always `en_US`. If I hardcode the corresponding locale for the `getMessage` call, I'm able to retrieve the correct message(s). So I know the setup/configuration works for the most part.

---

Clients are sending the locale using the `Accept-Language` header — and values like: `de-DE`, `en-US`, etc.

Comment: I suggest you put a breakpoint in the `resolveLocale` method of class `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`, so you can see what is going on, and perhaps figure out why it doesn't resolve as you expected.

Comment: Indeed, I tried such things before posting; it never stops at that method but at startup time.

Comment: Do you find any solutions for this using Jersey with Spring?

Comment: I tried same setup. Change your messages property files with Locale lang values. For an example not messages_en_US.properties, use messages_en.properties. Then it works fine. For the local values refer the Locale.

Comment: If you need to use property files with country specific, please refer my answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 8):

You need add an LocaleChangeInterceptor and configure the bean as follow:
Refer [Spring Boot internationalization](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization) for more

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}
```

If you want to use "Accept-Language" header only, then you can extend AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver and can customize:

```
package com.deb.demo.config;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver;

public class CustomLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver {


    List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(new Locale("en"),new Locale("es"),new Locale("fr"));


  @Override
  public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getHeader("Accept-Language"))) {
         return Locale.getDefault();
       }
     List<Locale.LanguageRange> list = Locale.LanguageRange.parse(request.getHeader("Accept-Language"));
     Locale locale = Locale.lookup(list,LOCALES);
      return locale;
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a parameter in the URL; I can only rely on the `Accept-Language` header from the request(s).

Comment: You can refer https://blog.usejournal.com/spring-boot-rest-internationalization-9ab3fce2489

Comment: I looked at that one earlier also; that's why I specified that I was using _Spring Boot and Jersey to define the (RESTful) endpoints_. Somehow `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` always have the value from the JVM. I'm sure it's because Jersey is in the middle, but that's the current setup for the application and I can't change it. I'm using a workaround for the time being: a `ContainerRequestFilter`, reading the locale from the header and assigning it to `LocaleContextHolder`. In any case, that example works flawlessly if you use Spring Boot (and its MVC part).

Comment: Beware that Locale.lookup may return null, so you should return your default locale in this case too.

Answer (score 7):

I m using a bean

```
  @Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver slr = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.UK);
    return slr;
  }
```

then another one

```
  @Bean
  public LanguageUtil languageUtil() {
    return new LanguageUtil();
  }
```

with

```
  private Locale getLocale() {
    return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
  }

  public String getLocalizedMessage(String messageKey) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, null, getLocale());
  }
```

The header is saved into the LocaleContextHolder, and you can use it when you need it.

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver

```
public class AcceptHeaderResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver {

    List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(new Locale("en"), new Locale("ar"));

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerLang = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        return headerLang == null || headerLang.isEmpty()
                ? Locale.getDefault()
                : Locale.lookup(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(headerLang), LOCALES);
    }


}
```

And Don't forgot to use it in `@Configuration` file

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderResolver();
    return localeResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get this on a REST controller level, you can directly get the locale instance in the REST methods. Spring does this magic

```
@GetMapping("/status")
public ResponseEntitiy<String> getStatus(final Locale locale) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to extend `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`.
Create a bean definition such as:

```
@Bean
public LocalResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setSupportedLocales(Arrays.asList(new Locale("fa"), new Locale("en")));
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("fa"));
    return localeResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also implemented same scenario and it's works for me. For this, need to override the `resolveLocale` method in `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`.

Create component `LanguageResolver` for the custom implementation. Use `Locale.forLanguageTag(language)` to create locale from `accept-header` value. This will create a local with language and country code.

```
@Component
    public class LanguageResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver {
        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String language = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
            List<Locale> supportedLocales = getSupportedLocales();
            Locale defaultLocale = getDefaultLocale();
            Locale requestLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag(language);
    
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(language)) {
                return defaultLocale;
            } else if (supportedLocales.contains(requestLocale)) {
                return requestLocale;
            } else {
                return defaultLocale;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the configuration class create bean using custom `LanguageResolver` class.

```
@Configuration
    public class Internationalization extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Bean
        public AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
            final LanguageResolver resolver = new LanguageResolver();
            resolver.setSupportedLocales(Arrays.asList(Locale.GERMANY, Locale.US,Locale.UK));
            resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
            return resolver;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
            final ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            source.setBasename("language/messages");
            source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            return source;
        }
    }
```

Here `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` will invoke the override method in `LanguageResolver` class.

```
@Service
public class LocaleService {
    @Autowired
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    public String getMessage(String code) {
        return messageSource.getMessage(code, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    }
}
```

And property files are in path of resources -> language

```
messages_en_US.properties
messages_en_GB.properties
messages_de_DE.properties
```

Content of the file in the format of below

```
test.hello=Hello GERMANY
```

Tested method using below.

```
@RestController
    public class TestController {
        private LocaleService localeService;
    
        @Autowired
        public TestController(LocaleService localeService) {
            this.localeService = localeService;
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/local")
        public String getMessageForLocal() {
            return localeService.getMessage("test.hello");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The LocaleResolver bean that you create only gets used in Spring MVC and not in the Jersey container. It is the Spring's DispatcherServlet that uses the LocaleResolver.

So LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(); will return different local depending on if call in a Jersey controller or in a Spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Accept-Language` header in your api endpoint to get desired locale output. Then you have to add following configuration to parse and set the `Accept-Language` header value from incoming request.

```
@Configuration
public class I18NConfiguration {

    @Value("${i18n.locale.default:en-US}")
    private String defaultLocale;

    @Value("#{'${i18n.locale.supported: }'.split(',\\s*')}")
    private List<String> supportedLocales;

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver acceptHeaderLocaleResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(defaultLocale));

        if (supportedLocales != null && !supportedLocales.isEmpty()) {
            List<Locale> localeList = supportedLocales.stream().map(Locale::forLanguageTag).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
            acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setSupportedLocales(localeList);
        }
        return acceptHeaderLocaleResolver;
    }
}
```